# Apache and user management in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2

I have Ubuntu 10.1 installed and I have setup Apache2.

I am going to host about 4-5 websites on this machine, so I need to have a user that controls files/permissions for each website.

I have added a user named 'site1' to control site1.com.

I know I should change the root folder in my apache config to be /home/site1 for site1.com

But the apache server runs on the www-data user, which will not be allowed to perform in actions on /home/site1.

How do I add permissions for www-data to the necessary folders?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do it. Do the following as root (assuming the `site1` user and home directory have already been created):

```
cd /home/site1
mkdir -m 0770 public_html
chown site1:www-data public_html
chmod g+s public_html
```

This creates the directory `public_html` and makes it readable and writable by the `www-data` group. This should allow Apache to have full access to it. Any files or directories created there will also be owned by the `www-data` group, because the SGID bit is set on the directory.

Make `/home/site1/public_html` the root directory of `site1.com` in your Apache config. I feel it's better to put the web root in a subdirectory of `/home/site1`, rather than in `/home/site1` itself, to keep the `site1` user's dotfiles and other potentially sensitive bric-a-brac out of there.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting this right, you need to change the owner of the

```
/home/site1
```

to www-data?

If so, you can execute:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/site1
```

Comment: Yes, but I am going to upload files to that directory using the username site1, but the site is running on www-data so basically both users needs permissions to read/write the files on /home/site1

Comment: You can add user site1 to www-data group by using the following syntax: useradd -G group_name user_name