# Apache and user write access to the same file

Tags: permissions, groups

I have [looked](https://serverfault.com/questions/134692/apache-and-linux-file-permissions?rq=1) at [multiple](https://serverfault.com/questions/662945/apache-and-users-write-permission-issues) questions [about](https://serverfault.com/questions/796784/giving-apache2-write-access-to-a-user-directory) this [issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/142456/apache-and-php-write-permission) and very few are [resolved](https://serverfault.com/questions/204339/apache-and-user-management-in-ubuntu).

Basically I want to allow **both** my user and apache (www-data) to modify a file without using `chmod 777` permissions.

I added my user to the `www-data` group and the `www-data` user to my user group. Using `id` and `group` on my user and the `www-data` user shows both are in each others group.

The file in question is located in `/home/myuser/workspace/project/logs/log.txt` and its permissions are `644` - `myuser:www-data` with the folder it is in as `755` - `myuser:www-data`

This allows my application to write to the file (under my user) but apache cannot access the file. When I swap user permissions around `myuser:www-data` -> `www-data:myuser` then apache can access the file but my application cannot write to the file.

I have no idea what I am overlooking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [suEXEC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuEXEC) to run application with user's uid/gid.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the answer is obvious now that I've looked into permissions a little more. Most documentation recommends folders to be set at `755` and files `644`.

The first number is the user access and the second the user. In order to allow **both the user and group** to write to the file, the permissions need to be `664`

So for all files and folders in a certain (limited) directory `sudo chmod -R u+rw,g+rw`